# Under "all actions", why are edits called "revisions"?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, terminology

In order to edit a post, I click on a link called **edit**. To finish editing I click a button entitled **Save Edits**. Afterwards, the post says **edited 1 min ago**.

So why does the "all actions" section of my profile call these **revisions** and not **edits**?

[image: screenshot with bad freehand circle]

Answer (score 5):

Because [revision](https://www.google.com/search?q=revision) is a very common word and is a synonym of the word edition. When you view the edits on a post, it also says that the edits are revisions.

I mean, edition is a good word but revision is just more general, in terms of definition and how common the word is.

Comment: Indeed, each individual version of a post is commonly referred to as a "revision", while the act of creating a revision is an "edit". I think the two could be used interchangeably most of the time, but the real answer to "why is the profile calling these revisions and not edits?" is "why not?".

Comment: @AdamLear I'd say "for consistency", since almost everywhere else they are "edits". I agree that you might call the state of a post at some point in time a "revision", and that's why the history page says "revisions", but the all-actions list is different — it's primarily showing the actions themselves, which are usu. "edits".

Answer (score 3):

The action you perform is "edit".

The result of the action can be either

- Accepted
- Accepted and more edit (improve)
- Rejected
- Rejected and edited otherwise (improve)

IMHO, for the first and second case, "revised" is a more generic term, without a direct conflict of the "action". For example, an *improved edit* is still a *revision*, however, not a valid *edit by you* anymore.

The post got *revised*, but maybe not by the *"edit"* done by you. You were the one to spot and suggest the *"edit"* so the credit (also, + rep) is awarded to you in your profile. The post, however, will have the reference to the improver.

Comment: An improved edit is still an edit by you, your edit and the improved edit are distinct revisions (which you can see in the revision history)

Comment: @Cai I was referring to the final outcome.

Comment: The outcome is still an edit by you, the improved edit is simply *another* edit, exactly the same as if someone later saw your edit and made a second edit.

Comment: @Cai I am not arguing your point, but the the visible revision in the post body is the common part from the earlier suggested edit with the later improvements. It's mostly a matter of viewpoint and choice of wordings.